# Disable selection to a range of dates in FSCalendar ObjC

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, fscalendar

I'm new to ObjC and I'm using FSCalendar library. I need to disable selection to a range of dates. Eg: from date - 2018-01-01 and to date - 2018-12-30. I've used the following method to disable past dates.

`- (BOOL)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar shouldSelectDate:(NSDate *)date atMonthPosition:(FSCalendarMonthPosition)monthPosition`

Please help me to disable selection of a range of dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with FSCalendar, but I took a quick look and you should just be able to setup a startingDateToAvoid and endingDateToAvoid and then check if the date passed in from shouldSelectDate is within that range then return NO if it is (to disallow selection):

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FSCalendar.h"

@interface ViewController () <FSCalendarDelegate, FSCalendarDataSource>
@property (strong, nullable) NSDate *startingDateToAvoid;
@property (strong, nullable) NSDate *endingDateToAvoid;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
    self.startingDateToAvoid = [formatter dateFromString:@"2018-01-01"];
    self.endingDateToAvoid = [formatter dateFromString:@"2018-12-30"];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (BOOL)_shouldAllowSelectionOfDate:(NSDate *)date {
    // if you want it to be inclusive of the starting/ending dates (i.e. they can't select 2018-01-01 as well) then uncomment this line below
    /*if ([date isEqualToDate:self.startingDateToAvoid] || [date isEqualToDate:self.endingDateToAvoid]) {
        return NO;
    }*/
    // if the date passed in is between your starting and ending date, we don't want to allow selection
    if ([date compare:self.startingDateToAvoid] == NSOrderedDescending &&
        [date compare:self.endingDateToAvoid] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar shouldSelectDate:(NSDate *)date atMonthPosition:(FSCalendarMonthPosition)monthPosition {
    return [self _shouldAllowSelectionOfDate:date];
}

@end
```